# Apply all transforms? After qutting edit mode it resets everything back

Tags: transforms, edit-mode

In *Edit Mode* I apply few transforms to a grid (wrap, rotate, change location), but when I got back to the *Object Mode* - everything's gone, and all I see is my default grid.

What am I missing? How do I stop blender from erasing all changes I've made?

Comment: Please be more specific, some screenshots could help. What is the "grid" you mentioned and how do you apply transforms to it. If you want to [apply transforms](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) it's done in Object mode.

Comment: Does you mesh have any shapekeys?

Comment: Grid is a grid from Create -> Grid. Transforms are in Edit Mode, Mesh menu -> Transform (various options in this sub-menu). Yes, I do have shape keys.

Comment: That can also happen when you have keyframes already set for that object.  The moment you try and move to another frame, even just one, everything to do with those keyframes will return things to the way they were.

Comment: So you didn't apply any transforms to the mesh, you edited mesh in Edit mode with scale / grab / rotate etc. with shape keys added to the mesh. The reason are the [shapekeys](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html) present in your mesh, that's what they actually do - allow transitioning from one form into another. Either delete them or edit the mesh while Basis key is selected.